# How to set selected option based on radio buttons values with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I see many times similar questions was asked however my question has a small difference.

I have:

1. a batch of radio buttons each has 2 values
2. 1 select with options. And based on selected radio values the wanted OPTION will be selected.

I will be very happy and thankful to you guys if you can give me a small help with it.

*Right now I am facing the problem how to make jQuery not only react on change function of radio button, but also to get the value in case it already have been loaded chacked...*

I would first ignore the field with number, and get back to if after i will figur out with radio...

**So for example I want:**

if ***custom_field_7*** is ***female*** AND ***custom_field_1*** is ***0***

make ***SELECT.custom_field_user_role*** option ***recommandation3*** selected

This is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hgts6rn1/11/) I am working with

**HTML CODE:**

```
<ul>
  <!-- 1 -->
  <li id="wppb-form-element-23">
    <label for="custom_field_7">Your sex:</label>
      <ul class="wppb-radios">
        <li>
          <input value="female" id="female_23" name="custom_field_7" type="radio" required="" checked="">
          <label for="female_23">Female</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input value="male" id="male_23" name="custom_field_7" type="radio" required="">
            <label for="male_23">Male</label>
          </li>
      </ul>
   </li>


  <!-- 2 -->
   <li id="wppb-form-element-25">
                <label for="custom_field_9">Yout age:</label>
                <input name="custom_field_9" type="number" id="custom_field_9" value="12" required="">
   </li>
   <!-- 3 -->
   <li id="wppb-form-element-18">
     <label for="custom_field_1">Have you suffered?</label>
       <ul>
         <li>
           <input value="1" id="1_18" name="custom_field_1" type="radio" required="">
           <label for="1_18">Yes</label>
         </li>
         <li>
           <input value="0" id="0_18" name="custom_field_1" type="radio" required="">
           <label for="0_18">No</label>
         </li>
       </ul>
   </li>
<!-- select -->
       <li id="wppb-form-element-27">
                    <label for="custom_field_user_role">Select role:</label>
                    <select name="custom_field_user_role" id="" class="custom_field_user_role " required="">
              <option value="recommandation1" selected="selected">recommandation 1</option>
              <option value="recommandation2">recommandation 2</option>
              <option value="recommandation3">recommandation 3</option>
            </select>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
        $('input[name = custom_field_7]').change(function() {
                if($('input[name = custom_field_7]').attr('checked') == "checked") { 
            //alert ((this.value));

          if ((this.value) == 'male' ) {
            $('.custom_field_user_role option:eq(2)').attr('selected','selected');
          } else if ((this.value) == 'female' ) {
            $('.custom_field_user_role option:eq(0)').attr('selected','selected');
          }
        }
        });
});


/*
$(function() { 
$('input[name=custom_field_7]').change(function() { 
             var up_sex = (this.value);

          return (up_sex);
          });

    if (!$("input[name='custom_field_7']:checked").val()) {
        $('input[name=custom_field_7]').change(function() { 
             var up_sex = (this.value);

          alert (up_sex);
          });
    } else {
     var up_sex = $("input[name='custom_field_7']:checked").val();

     alert (up_sex);
    }
});
    */
```

Comment: I do not see any jQuery/JS code in your post. What have you tried so far? What Error do you encounter?

Comment: I believe 1st I must take apart all values from the form and keep them as a group of values (array). and after I can  play with statments.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were trying something a bit strangely. I suspect the issue was related to an ambiguous selector: `$('input[name = custom_field_7]')` This is going to be more than 1 element.

```
$(function() {
  $("input[name='custom_field_7']").change(function(e) {
    console.log("input[name='custom_field_7'] - Event: " + e.type);
    $("input[name='custom_field_7']").each(function(i, el) {
      if ($(el).is(":checked") && $(el).val() == 'male') {
        $('.custom_field_user_role > option:eq(2)').prop('selected', true);
        console.log(".custom_field_user_role opt(2) selected");
      }
      if ($(el).is(":checked") && $(el).val() == 'female') {
        $('.custom_field_user_role > option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true);
        console.log(".custom_field_user_role opt(0) selected");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/4ax1j8tq/14/

You might consider using a more specific selector in your if statement: `$("input[name='custom_field_7']:checked").val() == 'male'`

For options, you can try to use `.attr()` but `.prop()` is advised. [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. one question, what if the form is already loaded with one radio button checked and user don't want to change it?

Comment: @AndrewS you would then need to find another callback to bind to or use `setTimeout()` to trigger the check after a specific amount of time.